# Under What Conditions Can I name my CPT the same as my CPT Page?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, pages, slug

The story goes that you cannot have by default the same CPT slug as the page you need to create for your CPT. On a few occasions I've been able to do just that though  and have it work just fine. For example:

I create my CPT

```
register_post_type('schedule', array(
        'labels'            =>  array(
            'name'          =>      __('Events'),
            'singular_name' =>      __('Event'),
            'all_items'     =>      __('View Events'),
            'add_new'       =>      __('New Event'),
            'add_new_item'  =>      __('New Event'),
            'edit_item'     =>      __('Edit Event'),
            'view_item'     =>      __('View Event'),
            'search_items'  =>      __('Search Events'),
            'no_found'      =>      __('No Eventss Found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Events in Trash')
                                ),
        'public'            =>  true,
        'publicly_queryable'=>  true,
        'show_ui'           =>  true, 
        'query_var'         =>  true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' =>  false,
        'rewrite'           =>  array('slug' => 'schedule', 'with_front' => false),
        'capability_type'   =>  'post',
        'hierarchical'      =>  false,
        'menu_position'     =>  21,
        'supports'          =>  array('title','editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'has_archive'       =>  false
    ));
```

I have my CPT Page:

[image: Custom Post Type Page - With Same Slug]

My permalink structure is: `/press-releases/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`

Finally I have a page template called "page-schedule.php" where I then query my CPT and display it just fine, even paged. I'm not the only one who's been able to do this as I have seen a few posts on wordpress.org forums claiming to also have been able to do this.

My question is, what exactly causes this to happen and how can it be reproduced so I can achieve nice CPT permalink structures without plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing magical about it, your post type doesn't have an archive ( `has_archive` is false ), so there's no rewrite rule for your post type that matches just `/%post_type%/`, the only existing rules for your post type are for `/%post_type%/%some_other_thing%/`, so there's no clash with your page.